# Deno 500 error from dev.jspm.io installing dependencies

Tags: deno

I'm trying to run my first deno script which is pretty much from the denoDB docs, it just tries to connect to a database with a SQLite3 connector (I'm on a Macbook pro so it should be installed):

```
import { Database, SQLite3Connector } from 'https://deno.land/x/denodb/mod.ts';

const connector = new SQLite3Connector({
  filepath: './db.sqlite',
});

export const db = new Database(connector);
```

I'm running `deno run api/db.ts` and I get this error after a few successful downloads:

> Download https://deno.land/std@0.149.0/encoding/hex.ts

> Download https://deno.land/std@0.149.0/hash/_wasm/lib/deno_hash.generated.mjs

> error: Import 'https://dev.jspm.io/inherits@2.0' failed: 500 Internal Server Error
> at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zhomart/dex/930253915093e1e08d48ec0409b4aee800d8bd0c/lib-dyn/deps.ts:4:26

I've deleted my `/Users/<me>/Library/Caches/deno/deps/https` and reran the script a few times but I still can't get past this. In my browser trying to follow the URL `https://dev.jspm.io/inherits@2.0` does give me an error. What is going on here? There's not much code and I imagine it's not broken for everybody. What do I need to do to get this script to run without issues?

EDIT: it seems to be a library error https://github.com/eveningkid/denodb/issues/348

Answer (score 0):

This is an error caused by a nested depedency, from a project that is not maintained.
See this for more info: [https://jspm.org/jspm-dev-release]
The point is dev.jspm.io is now jspm.dev

A way to fix this is to fork and update depedencies.

Another thing, if you're not using deno deploy, you can just use this as a replacement for your denodb: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joeldesante/denodb/master/mod.ts

Just note that this script is no more maintained either, but it will fix your problem

*Edit*
I just made a dirty quick fix for deno deploy use this as a depedency isntead of denodb: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ninjinskii/denodb/master/mod.ts

Again, i may not maintain this script forever.

The best thing that can happen is an update from these libs maintainers